# App crashes while finding elements in array

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, binaryfiles

The input file is `in.wav`. I have to read chunks (succeeded) and to read samples to normalize the audio file...

The problem is that it crashes while trying to fing the `max` and `min` values of .wav file's samples.
It will just find the minimum value and the maximum one in the array, but **it crashes**...

Tell me what is wrong, please. I see no reason of such kind of behaviour.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "main.h"
#define hdr_SIZE 64

typedef struct FMT
{
    char        SubChunk1ID[4];
    int         SubChunk1Size;
    short int   AudioFormat;
    short int   NumChannels;
    int         SampleRate;
    int         ByteRate;
    short int   BlockAlign;
    short int   BitsPerSample;

} fmt;

typedef struct DATA
{
    char        Subchunk2ID[4];
    int         Subchunk2Size;
    int         Data[441000]; 
} data;

typedef struct HEADER
{
    char        ChunkID[4];
    int         ChunkSize;
    char        Format[4];
    fmt         S1;
    data        S2;
} header;



int main()
{
    FILE *input = fopen( "in.wav", "rb");   /// nameIn

    if(input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open wave file (input)\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    FILE *output = fopen( "out.wav", "wb"); /// nameOut
    header hdr;


    fread(&hdr, sizeof(char), hdr_SIZE, input); 
    /* NOTE: Chunks has been copied successfully. */


    char *ptr;  
    long n = hdr.S2.Subchunk2Size;


    /// COPYING SAMPLES...
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(n));

    fread( ptr, 1, n, input );   


    int min = ptr[0], max = ptr[0], i;

    /* THE PROBLEM IS HERE: */
    for ( i = 0; i <= n; i++ )  // Finding 'max' and 'min'.
        {
            if ( ptr[i] < min )    
                min = ptr[i];
            if ( ptr[i] > max ) 
                max = ptr[i];
    }

    printf("> > >%d__%d\n", min, max);    // Displaying of 'min' and 'max'.

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}
```

**Why does it behaves itself so strange?**

Comment: edit your code  :   for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )   index must be in [0 .. n-1 ]

Comment: quite a good remark, but it didn't help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is in (at least)

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(n));
```

because **sizeof(n) is 4**, sizeof(n) equals to sizeof(long). You just allocated 4 bytes for ptr.

The solution of your problem is the following:

```
ptr = malloc(n); 
/* It will allocate the size of 'n' (27164102 bytes),
   but not the data type size (4 bytes). */
```

Comment: Are you sure? Because `long n = hdr.S2.Subchunk2Size;` --> n = 27164102 (the 'data' chunk's size).

Comment: Yes, sizeof(n) is 4. Try `malloc(n)`

Comment: sizeof return its date type's size, not the data's size

Answer (score 4):

Arrays is indexed from zero to `n-1`, but in following piece of code:

```
for ( i = 0; i <= n; i++ )
```

you are trying to read from zero to `n`

Comment: @Julian although this one will in many cases create less spectacular problems both make your program go outside its allocated memory, both are equally wrong and both should be solved.